# Android google-services configuration file

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I have in project implemented a google-services.json for push notifications, now i need to add another google-services.json regarding analytics. How to implement both ? Do i need to merge these jsons or they must be separated ?

Comment: *Do i need to merge these jsons* yes, ideally you would download a merged one from console

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: merge them in console